# My dragon tree has lost all its leaves from one stem in the past week?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, leaves, dracaena

[image]We’ve had our dragon tree for around 2/3 months and it’s been fine. Within the past week or two, all leaves from one stem have completely dropped off, and the tips are slightly bendy. The other stems/leaves are completely fine so not sure what’s happened. Is there any way it can be saved or anyway to stop the same thing happening to the rest of the tree?

Comment: When you say the tips are slightly bendy, does that mean soft? Check the whole stem for soft or soggy areas, with or without discoloration - the whole stem is obviously not visible in the photo

Comment: Just the tip, the stem feels fine and sturdy. It just the very tip where the leaves would come out

Answer (score 1):

If, as you say, it's only the tips of that stem which are a bit soft, I'd recommend cutting it with clean, sharp secateurs just below where it branches out, so you've just got a single stem left. Inspect the inside of what you cut off, and the inside on the cut stem - you're looking for  any signs of blackening or streakiness. If the stem you've cut seems 'clean' to look at, leave it be and wait for it to sprout again, but keep any eye on it, in case whatever's happened to the top is actually spreading downwards, or if problems appear lower down the stem as time goes on. If the inside of the cut stem is not 'clean', cut it down lower until you get to a point where it is 'clean'; if there's isn't a point where that happens, cut it out right at the base of the plant.

It's likely to be some kind of fungal problem - if you are keeping the soil too wet, this is more likely to occur. Water only when the surface of the soil feels dry to the touch, but not so dry its shrunken from the sides, then water thoroughly, allowing excess to drain away from the holes in the pot. Empty out any outer container or tray the plant is standing in thirty minutes after watering to make sure it's not left sitting in water. I'm obviously assuming the plant is in a pot with drainage holes...