# Dragon tree leaves drooping and falling off – Can it be saved and should I trim the stems?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-care, rot, trimming

Edit: I reposted this on Reddit and from the answers I got there I decided on repotting, trimming the leaves and lightly trimming the stems. Going to hope for the best now. Cheers.

Is it too late to save this dragon tree?

It had been kept in the shade for several weeks and was likely overwatered. After some leaves started yellowing and falling off, I moved it to the window sill. But at this time of the year, direct sunlight is scarce, and after a few days all of the leaves started drooping overnight.

I looked at several similar questions such as [this](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/57958/my-dragon-tree-has-lost-all-its-leaves-from-one-stem-in-the-past-week), and gather there is some root rot going on, but repotting it or changing the earth could be too much stress for the plant at this point.

So I guess my questions right now are:

- **Should I trim off the remaining leaves?** You can see they are all yellow at the base.
- **Should I go further and cut off the stem tips?** The tips got soft, but are not empty or dry yet.

I did remove all of the leaves that fell off at a touch or where entirely dried out. The ones that remain still seem to be alive.

Please give me some hope, I really want to help the poor little plant.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Having killed more than a few of these I can say with confidence that repotting is not required.

It has been overwatered and the end of the stems are dead.

- Increase the light
- reduce the water
- cut the main stem a few inches above the soil

And then, be patient... new growth could take months